# Cutting a mesh with another mesh

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I've seen this done before but it was a long time ago. I don't know what it's called so forgive me if there's already a thread like this. Say you have a cube and you put a sphere inside the cube half way so that half of the sphere is poking out. You then use that sphere to carve out the other half of the sphere into the cube as if it's leaving a footprint.

Please redirect me to any duplicate post out there!

NOTE: I'd prefer to avoid using the *Knife* tool.

Comment: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Booleans

Comment: If for some reason, the marked question doesn't help, there are lots of answers you can go through [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=cut+mesh+boolean).